# Visual studio community 2015 not showing output

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have just installed Visual Studio community 2015 and wrote my first code and it's not showing output for some reason please do help me here,

i am attaching image.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sT3kK.png

Answer (score 2):

See that yellow arrow?  Your program is paused at the beginning of `main()`.  In Visual Studio, press F5 to continue or F10 to step through each statement.

Answer (score 0):

From what i can see on the screen, you're using the local debugger which has stopped at main() (yellow arrow on the left margin of the line). See if you can continie debugging to continue the program or open a built .exe file